# Advance Touchpad Gesture Like Deepin OS?

Tags: touchpad, gestures, touchegg

need multi finger touchpad gesture! i tested touchegg.. here is only 3 finger feature (which used to minimize or maximize program).i need more feature! Extremely needed swipe program feature [alt+tab] on touchpad like macbook or deepin linux os !

Answer (score 2):

For now the most powerful tool for working with touchpad gestures I ever found is Fusuma. It allows to map any keyboard combination to pitch or swipe gesture with *N* fingers and can be configured via config file in `~/.config/fusuma/config.yml`.

My config file, for example, looks like this: https://gist.github.com/s-kostyuk/6ac4c1a13babffcbd5587278af6e2fe7

More info is available by this link, in its GitHub repository: https://github.com/iberianpig/fusuma